# Anyone know what chip this is?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, markings

Trying to find a datasheet for it. Best I can make out from markings is:

8211SO

VM1AP5 1

K240 1

Could also be 3211SO? Not very legible.

Pins 5,6,7,8 are all shorted together if that helps.

If you can help me identify this chip it would be much appreciated.[image: Unknown chip]

Comment: What's the context of the circuit surrounding this? Four pins shorted together could suggest a power FET in that package, but this is just a hunch.

Comment: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX8211-MAX8212.pdf

Comment: @Codebeat I found that in my searches. What I don't understand is why pins 5-8 are shorted together. That shorts V+ and GND pins together.